# TokenMismatchException in Laravel with React, fetch

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, fetch, laravel-5.3

i making post request in resource controller, and adding X-CSRF-TOKEN in headers:

```
 let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('X-CSRF-TOKEN', document.querySelector('meta[name=csrf-token]').getAttribute('content'));
    fetch('/housings', { method: 'POST', headers: headers }).then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        this.state.housings.push(res);
      });
    this.setState({
      housings: this.state.housings,
    });
```

But after request i recessive 500 error with message TokenMismatchException.
If i look in chrome network tab i can look my x-csrf-token header in request.